# Jquery append textbox with unique PHP number

Tags: php, jquery

I have a site that appends a textbox to a div when the user clicks a button.  The textbox works great.  Now, I would like to generate a unique number for the `id` of each box.  The following code is giving me 0 as the `id` of each box.  I'm trying to get them to go 1,2,3,4...

Code:

```
<?php $x=0; ?> 

$("#add").click(function(){
    $('#boxes').append(<input type="text" id="<?php echo $x; $x++; ?>">);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code is excuted earlier before the javascript code is executed.  But in your code example you try to execute both at the same time. That is just not the case.

Instead of a PHP variable you need to use a javascript variable:

```
var x = 0;
$("#add").click(function() {
    $('#boxes').append('<input type="text" id="' + ++x + '">');
});
```

Comment: Yes, there is no need for PHP in this circumstance. Javascript has similar variable, and 'counting' features

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP variable as base for your javascript variable or just plain javascript.

```
//note, $x can be anything e.g. 1
var boxID = '<?php echo $x; ?>'; 

$("#add").click(function(){
    //insert new box, increase boxID
    $('#boxes').append('<input type="text" id="'+boxID+'">');
    boxID++;
});
```

Comment: In this case, x must be an interger. If it will not be an interger, you need to wrap the php tag in quotes